# Creating Dashboard Using External Data (Google Spreadsheet) - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, charts, google-sheets, google-visualization

Hey guys i am finding it hard to understand how the google visualization java script works as i am new to it. However i did have a crack at it following the documentations that have and managed to created a simple chart displaying the data from the a spreadsheet.

Now however i have been trying to implement added interactivity such as a slider to my chart and also a pie chart, just for testing sake and seeing if i can get it to work with my data.

My problem however to put it simply is that it does not work, nothing shows on the webpage and i have made sure i have linked the JS file correctly to my HTML file.

```
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['controls']});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawDashboard);

function drawDashboard() {
    var query = new google.visualization.Query(
      '//docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FOVmfesx7ATNe8qjWjkU2GbjBCBZxL0BRswJv6rcGPs/gviz/tq?gid=1324373577&tq=select%20B,C%20where%20B%20%3C%3E%20%22%22');
  query.send(handleQueryResponse);

}

function handleQueryResponse(response) {
  if (response.isError()) {
    alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
    return;
  }

}
var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
            document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));

    // Create a range slider, passing some options
        var donutRangeSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
          'controlType': 'NumberRangeFilter',
          'containerId': 'filter_div',
          'options': {
            'filterColumnLabel': 'Number Attended'
          }
        });

    // Create a pie chart, passing some options
        var pieChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
          'chartType': 'PieChart',
          'containerId': 'chart_div',
          'options': {
            'width': 300,
            'height': 300,
            'pieSliceText': 'value',
            'legend': 'right'
          }
        });

    // Establish dependencies, declaring that 'filter' drives 'pieChart',
        // so that the pie chart will only display entries that are let through
        // given the chosen slider range.
        dashboard.bind(donutRangeSlider, pieChart);

        // Draw the dashboard.
        dashboard.draw(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `google.visualization.Dashboard` until it has been loaded.

Here is a simplified version to demonstrate.

```js
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {
    'packages': ['controls']
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
    $("#out").text($("#out").text() + "google.visualization is " + google.visualization + " in the callback.\n");
});

$("#out").text($("#out").text() + "google.visualization is " + google.visualization + " out here.\n");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

You need to re-factor your code so it doesn't try to use google.visualization until it has been loaded.